# Keep getting a syntax error when using MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to run the following code in MySQL without using a procedure or function. I keep getting a syntax error. Does anyone see anything wrong with this code. Am I able to run this code without using a procedure or function.

```
DECLARE @Machine varchar(30);
 SET @Machine = @MachineType;



 IF @Machine = 'server' 
THEN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total Servers'
 FROM agentcomputers AS A
 WHERE A.groupid IN('521','637');

 ELSEIF @Machine = 'bdr server'
 THEN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total BDR Servers'
 FROM agentcomputers AS A
 WHERE A.groupid =521;

 ELSEIF @Machine = 'non-bdr server'
 THEN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total Non-BDR Servers'
 FROM agentcomputers AS A
 WHERE A.groupid =637;


ELSEIF @Machine = 'workstation'
 THEN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total Workstations'
 FROM agentcomputers AS A
 WHERE A.groupid =638;

 ELSEIF @Machine = 'laptop'
 THEN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total Laptops'
 FROM agentcomputers AS A
 WHERE A.groupid =650;

 ELSEIF @Machine = 'monitored computer'
 THEN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total Monitored Computers'
 FROM agentcomputers AS A
 WHERE A.groupid =1;

 ELSEIF @Machine = 'new computer'
 THEN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total New Computers'
 FROM agentcomputers AS A
 WHERE A.groupid =648;


ELSEIF @Machine = 'managed service'
 THEN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total Managed Services'
 FROM agentcomputers AS A
 WHERE A.groupid =522;

 ELSEIF @Machine = 'allmachines'
 THEN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total Machines'
 FROM agentcomputers AS A
 WHERE A.groupid IN('1','521','522','637','638','648','650');

 /*
 THESE IF STATEMENTS RETURN THE COUNTS FOR THE MOBIL DEVICES
 */

 ELSEIF @Machine = 'phone'
 THEN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total Mobil Phones'
 FROM mobiledevices AS M
 INNER JOIN mobilemastergroups AS MM
 ON MM.groupID = M.deviceType 
WHERE M.deviceType=2;

 ELSEIF @Machine = 'tablet'
 THEN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total Mobil Tablets'
 FROM mobiledevices AS M
 INNER JOIN mobilemastergroups AS MM
 ON MM.groupID = M.deviceType 
WHERE M.deviceType=3;

 ELSEIF @Machine = 'ios'
 THEN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total Mobil iOS Devices'
 FROM mobiledevices AS M
 INNER JOIN mobilemastergroups AS MM
 ON MM.groupID = M.deviceType 
WHERE M.deviceType=4;

 ELSEIF @Machine = 'android'
 THEN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total Mobil Android Devices'
 FROM mobiledevices AS M
 INNER JOIN mobilemastergroups AS MM
 ON MM.groupID = M.deviceType 
WHERE M.deviceType=5;


ELSEIF @Machine = 'allmobil'
 THEN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total Mobil Devices'
 FROM mobiledevices AS M;




END IF;
```

Comment: Don't `DECLARE` user variables

Comment: What's the error you're receiving?

Comment: syntax error near IF @Machine = 'server'  
THEN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Total Servers' 
 FROM agentcomputers AS A                                            ALSO I removed the DECLARE Statement and got the same error

Comment: No clue what the error is but try running only one part/section of your IF statement at a time to see if you can isolate the error.  If it comes down to it, make sure all your SELECT statements run fine on their own and make sure that it doesn't have to do with the assignment of a variable to the result of any of the SELECT statements.  Troubleshoot: tear it apart, isolate the error.  ALso, I just noticed that when you use an IN statement you refer to the groupID as a string/text but the rest of the time its numeric (no quotes).